# ADF Inline frame

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a main page which has two regions .
Region 1 is running a taskflow with has a adf inline frame to render a pdf document( we are using third party renderer ).
Region 2 has a task flow which show details based on events happening on region 1 .
We want bi directional communication between region1 and region 2.
Now problem is whenevr wehenever we raise a contextual event and it gets porcessesed by event hadnlers it reloads ADF iframe content .Irrespective of the fact that 
event is not meant of that region .Other components in the region1 stays same that is they are not gettinf refreshed .
Is this a configuration issue .
Note FRAME BRUSting is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Use partial page refresh, I think it should solve your problem. You can try with partialSubmit and partialTrigger or follow this link: http://www.adftips.com/2010/10/adf-ui-refreshing-page-or-region.html